# How to update data in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, frameworks

I'm having trouble updating records in my database with laravel. I want the user to be able to change its name/email address by filling in a form. however, this is not working. it is giving me this error 'Creating default object from empty value' and i have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

My update function in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = UserModel::find($id);

    $name->name = $request->input('name');
    $email->email = $request->input('email');

    $user->save();

    return view('edit');
}
```

My form in my view:

```
 <form id="form" action="{{ action('AccountController@update') }}">
    @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Edit Acount info</h5>
            <label for="">Name:</label><input name="name" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" class="form-control" id="edit_name">
            <label for="">E-mail:</label><input name="email" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" class="form-control" id="edit_email">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a id="btn_link">Edit</a></button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

My Model:

```
 class UserModel extends Model
 {
   protected $table = 'users';
   protected $primarykey = 'id';
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I changed my answer to also include changes to convert your request to a POST one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to the object `name` and `email`. Both do not exist. You probably meant to do this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    auth()->user()->update([
        'name'  => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email')
    ]);

    return view('edit');
}
```

**Edit**: Admittedly, it's quite odd to see an update action being done with `GET`. I'd change it to `POST`. Also changed action to use a named route. You could keep your action helper if you wish.

```
<form id="form" action="{{ route('account.update') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Edit Account info</h5>
            <label for="">Name:</label><input name="name" type="text" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" class="form-control" id="edit_name">
            <label for="">E-mail:</label><input name="email" type="text" value="{{ auth()->user()->email }}" class="form-control" id="edit_email">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a id="btn_link">Edit</a></button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Make sure your route is also changed to a `POST` one if it isn't already one.

```
Route::post('account/update', 'AccountController@update')->name('account.update');
```

Not sure if the above is your actual route, but you could easily change that :)

Comment: @Mozamil I tried the code you provided for me. I also changed my current route to a post route. It is still not working, it keeps telling me the values are null and i have no idea why the name and email are null values.

Comment: could you `dd(auth()->user())` in the controller?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dd(auth()->user->name, auth()->user()->email));`

Comment: I tried dd(auth()->user->name, auth()->user()->email)); and it is returning the correct data.

Comment: Performed some updates to the controller code and the blade file, including the route. I simplified it a bit. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error, it should work:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = UserModel::find($id);

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');

    $user->save();

    return view('edit');
}
```

That also a way:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = UserModel::find($id);

    $user->update([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email')
    ]);

    return view('edit');
}
```

Comment: I tried using the last method but it is still giving me errors. This time it is telling me this 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null'. But I don't understand why the name is null.

Comment: dd($request->alll()) - what do you see that you've got in the request?

Comment: When i do dd($request->all()); i dont see any data in the request.

Comment: Worth mentioning that your update is a `GET` request.

Comment: @Mozammil where do I change this to POST?

Comment: I mean there's no need to if your route is a GET one, but it is quite odd for an update action.

Comment: @stefandeboer your form declaration doesn't have a `method="post"` so it will take get as default. It means anyone can do update action on by just having the url. You can change to `PUT' see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing This means you've to change your route declaration to the method you use.